# link docker containers and use wildcard subdomains

Tags: docker

I have two docker containers (container_one and container_two), one is linked to the other container_one >>link>> container_two.

when i run a curl command from within container_one using the address: http://container_two/index.php the curl command executes successfully as expected.

however, i would like to introduce a wildcard subdomain so that i can attach any number of subdomains to container_two (eg: site1.container_two, site2.container_two, *.container_two, etc). Obviously, calling a curl command from container_one: http://site1.container_two/index.php does not work with linking alone.

Does anyone know how this would be possible with a docker run command or perhaps some other way?

Answer (score 6):

Basically, you cannot do this with just `--link` flags, because `--link` adds an entry to the `/etc/hosts` file to facilitate this inter-container communication, and `/etc/hosts` files do not support wildcard entries.

However, you could set up a DNS server on your `container_one`, and set up your wildcard host (or subdomain records) on that DNS server to point to your `container_two` (and forward all other requests to your actual DNS for all other hostnames), and then specify `--dns=127.0.0.1` in your `docker run` command for `container_one`. This seems a bit hacky, but what happens is that `container_one` will then use `127.0.0.1` (localhost) when it encounters a hostname it does not recognize in `/etc/hosts`, and the DNS on `container_one` will point to `container_two` for subdomains (and all other requests forwarding to your external DNS infrastructure).

You can find more information about this in [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/#configuring-dns). Good luck!

Comment: Example implementation using docker-compose and a third container for dns: https://gist.github.com/NAR8789/92da076d0c35b434107fb4f4f198fd12